# Is it possible to disable the file activity in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-library, modern-document-library

I am asking about [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/file-activity-in-a-document-library-6105ecda-1dd0-4f6f-9542-102bf5c0ffe0) functionality. We don't want it to be visible. Can it be de-activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, No.

Currently there is no SharePoint out of the box option or setting available to deactivate the file activity section in document library details pane.

If you want Microsoft to provide settings for enabling/disabling  the file activity section in document library details pane, add new feedback/idea at: [SharePoint feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)